# Posting a multi-part series on how to solve a puzzle?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, self-answer

So, as an example, let's take the Rubik's Cube (since it's been getting popular since that question Emrakul posted about 4x4 positions not appearing on a 3x3) which obviously **should not be used, as there are plenty of tutorials on the Internet**. But assuming the Rubik's Cube was a puzzle not fairly known with plenty of tutorials on *the net*, would it be allowed to ask and self answer a bunch of parts in a series explaining how to solve it?

I'm not saying I'm going to do it, but I'm still trying to get a grip on what is on and off topic, and how far exactly it goes.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to keep as much information in one spot as is reasonable. If there's no reason to split up the questions, don't.

A more technical interpretation of the rules follows.

Each question on SE must stand alone. That doesn't preclude related questions (e.g. the Spaghetti party), but each question should be completely understandable without reference to any other question; the others must simply provide context and supplemental information. Notice that this is the same standard we expect of answers.

So, if you can split up your series into logically complete and consistent blocks without any reliance on other parts, go ahead. Otherwise, keep it as one question.

That said, if you chop up your question too finely (more than 2-3 parts, usually), people are likely to object, complain, downvote, and vote to close.

The only way to tell for sure is to try, and the community will downvote and close your questions if they don't like it.

Comment: I understand this, but say for the Rubik's cube example, we had "How to solve the Rubik's cube [Part 1!] Solving the white cross" that's perfectly standalone, and part 2 "How to solve the Rubik's cube [Part 2!] Solving the white corners" which is also perfectly standalone. But together, forms a complete guide.

Comment: I've added a bit more. Basically, if you do it right, it's not technically against the rules, but unless you do it very, very carefully, it's going to seem like you're rep-whoring and backfire.

Comment: Interesting... I'd say 5 parts though before downvotes.